# Committing to Master Branch from Tag

Tags: git, tagging

I have checked out a tag from my master branch.  I made some changes and am wondering if there is a way to commit/merge those changes with the branch?  Otherwise I see my only option as pulling the latest and then redoing the changes there.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're now in the ["detached HEAD"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3965714/720999) state.  So just fork a branch off your HEAD

```
git checkout -b newbranch
```

and then decide what to do next in a convenient regular situation where you just have several branches to manipulate.

For instance, you might want to decide to merge your developments to the "master" branch, then do

```
git checkout master
git merge newbranch
```

After that you can get rid of that temporary branch using

```
git branch -d newbranch
```

P.S.
Also note that tags are not on any branch. Tags refer to commits, and those commits may be referenced by more than one branch or by no branch at all.